# Test multivariate normality of 2D binned data in R

Tags: r, statistics, mle, hypothesis-test

I have some heatmap data and I want a notion as to whether that heat map is 'centered' around the middle of my image or skewed to one side (in R). My data is too big to give an example here, so this is some fake data of the same form (but in real life my `intensity` values are not uniformly distributed, I assume they are binned counts from an underlying multivariate normal distribution but I don't know how to code that as a reproducible example).

```
set.seed(42)
tibble(
  x = rep(0:7, each = 8),
  y = rep(0:7, 8),
  intensity = sample(0:10, 64, replace = TRUE)
)
```

[image: example original heatmap]

The `x` value here is the horizontal index of a pixel, the `y` value is the vertical index of a pixel and `intensity` is the value of that pixel according to a heatmap. I have managed to find a "centre" of the heatmap by marginalising these intensity values and finding the marginalised mean for `x` and `y`, but how would I perform a hypothesis test on whether the underlying multivariate normal distribution was centered around a certain point? In this case I would like to have a test statistic (more specifically a -log10 p-value) as to whether the underlying multivariate normal distibution that generated this count data is centered around the point `c(3.5, 3.5)`.

Furthermore, I would also like a test statistic (again, more specifically a -log10 p-value) as to whether the underlying distribution that generated the count data actually is multivariate normal.

This is all part of a larger pipeline where I would like to use `dplyr` and `group_by` to perform this test on multiple heatmaps at once so if it is possible to keep this in tidy format that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[A little bit of googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=multivariate+shapiro+wilk+test) finds [this web page](https://universeofdatascience.com/shapiro-wilk-test-for-univariate-and-multivariate-normality-in-r/) which suggests `mvnormtest::mshapiro.test`.

```
mshap <- function(z, nrow = round(sqrt(length(z)))) {
   mvnormtest::mshapiro.test(matrix(z, nrow = nrow))
}
mshap(dd$intensity)
```

If you want to make this more tidy-like you could do something with map/nest/etc..

I'm not quite sure how to test the centering hypothesis (likelihood ratio test using `mnormt::dmnorm` ?)

Comment: Forgive me if I am misunderstanding, but I belive the S-W test is for testing multivariate normality of observations of data (hence why it is sensitive to transposition and colinearity). My data is not recording observations of variables, but rather a count of a discretisation of these variables and so it is my understanding that the SW test won't work. This would require a transformation of my data from count data back to observation of variables (or at least expected observations of my variables given the counts) and I was hoping there would be a function/test that didn't need this

Comment: Also, my apologies as the question might have been able to be phrased better. The idea of this heat map is that it is showing intensity within each region that is a discretisation of R^2. I.e. the higher the intesity within a region would correspond to more samples from a multivariate normal distribution over x and y being found within that bin.

Comment: You could use a chi-squared test based on the integrated densities of the MVN in each bin (`mnormt` might have something for this ...)